# How to roughly say "Be grateful you have a job in a pandemic"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

my Latin is pretty rusty from high school, but I'd like to translate the phrase "Be grateful you have a job in a pandemic", as it was the feedback we received from my company's recent staff survey. Apologies for the word mangling, I'm guessing its something like

Numquid gratiam laboris pestilentia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this is sufficient: *pestilentia serpente pro labore gratiam habeas* 'Be grateful for the toiling while the disease is spreading.'

Hortatory subjunctive and ablative absolute are our friends.

Comment: Many thanks Tuomo!

Comment: @Rob Remember to click the checkmark if this answer satisfies your question.